# Use URL named anchor to open up a div through javascript

Tags: javascript, anchor

I have a div on my page that is hiding overflow text (with a fixed height). On that same page, I have a link with the following code, that when clicked, would maximize the height of the div and reveal the full text:

```
javascript:showcontent('content2')
```

I was just wondering how I can set up a named anchor, like http://site.com/jobs#showcontent, that would automatically open up the div as well. Of course, it would act the same if #showcontent was not added to the URL.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: so your just trying to add something like `#showcontent` to the end of your url if they click your link to expand the div?